# Get Datetime of month and year

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a month range of the first of the month to the last two days (-2)

So for example:  It is May 1st 2015 or 05/01/2015.

I want to pull the last two days as the end date 04/29/15 and the first of that month 04/01/15.

So my range would be 04/01/15 - 04/29/15 when the current day is 05/01/2015.

So if the current day is 05/02/15 I want to get the range 04/01/15 - 04/30/15.

But once it hits 05/03/15 it switches back to 05/01/15.

So this is what I have so far:

```
    static DateTime GetMonthly = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);

    static string StartMonthly = ?????

    static string EndMonthly = GetMonthly.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

I know how to get the EndMonthly but not the first day of the GetMontly -2 days.

Also I would need to grab the year according to the GetMonthly.  So when its 01/01/2016, I would want to grab 12/01/15 - 12/30/15

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: "But once it hits 05/03/15 it switches back to 05/01/15."  Why is this incorrect?  The first of the month of 05/03 - 2 days (05/01) is 05/01.

Comment: So I figured it out, I did this: static string StartMonthly = GetMonthly.Year + "/" + GetMonthly.Month + "/" + "01"; but how do I get the month with a 0 in front of single digit months.

Comment: You could create a new `DateTime` providing the month/year values, and setting the day value to 1 to get the start of the month.  Then get your end of range by `firstOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-2);`

Comment: @BillyHen that's a job for [`.ToString` formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: this would help new DateTime(GetMonthly.Year, GetMonthly.Month, 1);

Comment: @ryanyuyu GetMonthly.Month.ToString("MM") doesn't work tho?

Comment: @Billy Hen...Look up DateTime in the C# API and scroll down to ToString

Comment: Could you perhaps try to reword what you are trying to do?  I read over it again and now I am confused.  Are you trying to find how many days between the first of last month and 2 days prior to today?

Comment: @dubstylee Thanks for your help.  I was trying to get the first of the month of a particular DateTime.  I was able to do this by: static string StartMonthly = GetMonthly.Year + "/" + GetMonthly.Month.ToString("ss") + "/" + "01";

Comment: @dubstylee But I do not know how to make the GetMonthly.Month into a 05 string instead of 5

Comment: @BillyHen rather than using a `static string`, you should make your `StartMonthly` be a `DateTime`, then you can use the formatting of the `DateTime.ToString()` method: `StartMonthly.ToString("yy/MM/dd");`

Comment: @BillyHen format the entire DateTime at once like `"MM/dd/yy`.  Also `DateTime.ToShortDateString()` should work too.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is a better way to do it but I ended up doing this:

```
static DateTime GetMonthly = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2);

static string StartMonthly = GetMonthly.Year + "/" + GetMonthly.Month.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "/" + "01";

static string EndMonthly = GetMonthly.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Just wanted to show anyone who asks this question again.